# Replace method is receiving list when it should be receiving string

Tags: python

I currently have a list of strings, let's say like this:

```
strings = ['Hello my name is John.', 'What is your name?', 'My name is Peter.']
```

and I want to replace the punctuation in each of those strings, and also replace them with lists of their tokens. The code that I wrote to do that is:

```
# Original list:
# strings = ['Hello my name is John.', 'What is your name?', 'My name is Peter.']

PUNC = ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']

for i in range(len(strings)):
    for token in PUNC:
        if token in strings[i]:
            strings[i] = strings[i].replace(token, '').split()

# New desired list:
# strings = [['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', John'],
#            ['What', 'is', 'your', 'name'],
#            ['My', 'name', 'is', Peter']]
```

The code works fine when I run it on individual string elements, but gives me the following warning when I run the code I wrote above:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I've set up breakpoints using Python Debugger and tried going through the code, and I noticed that before I run the above code the data is fine, but after I run it only the first two elements are converted into their tokenized versions and the code throws the error afterwards. This error shouldn't even be occurring since the original list only contains string elements.

Does anybody know why this might be the case? Thank you.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't demonstrate the issue, you need a string with more than one type of punctuation

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `.split()`. It turns the string into a list:

```
PUNC = ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']

for i in range(len(strings)):
    for token in PUNC:
        if token in strings[i]:
            strings[i] = strings[i].replace(token, '')
```

You also don't need the `if` statement:

```
PUNC = ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']

for i in range(len(strings)):
    for token in PUNC:
        strings[i] = strings[i].replace(token, '')
```

If you want to split all strings, do it at the end:

```
PUNC = ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']

for i in range(len(strings)):
    for token in PUNC:
        strings[i] = strings[i].replace(token, '')
    strings[i] = strings[i].split()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call `split` after each `replace`, turning `strings[i]` into a list. Just do it once after all replacements.

Also, you don't need to check if a characted is in the string to replace it. Furthermore, using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) allows you to avoid using indices all the time.

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
strings = ['Hello my name is John.', 'What is your name?', 'My name is Peter.']

# Original list:
# strings = ['Hello my name is John.', 'What is your name?', 'My name is Peter.']

PUNC = ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']

for i, s in enumerate(strings):
    for token in PUNC:
        s = s.replace(token, '')
    strings[i] = s.split()

print(strings)
# [['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'John'], ['What', 'is', 'your', 'name'], ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Peter']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get your desired list with the below code:

```
strings = ['Hello my name is John.', 'What is your name?', 'My name is Peter.']
PUNC = ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']
new_list =[]
for i in range(len(strings)):
    for token in PUNC:
        if token in strings[i]:
            strings[i] = strings[i].replace(token, '').split()
    new_list.append(strings[i])
print(new_list)
```

[image]